# Grunt Notify Failure on MacOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, gruntjs, grunt-notify

I am working with a fairly complex existing software system that builds on MacOS.  It is built using Maven.  The build has worked correctly for me in the past and currently works for others on my team so this is pointing to something that I did locally to cause a failure.  I recently had to reinstall npm, grunt and bower. Right now there is a clean install of all three on my machine.  When it gets to the part that uses grunt notify I get a fatal error:

```
>> npm Fatal error: spawn /private/tmp/git-repo/lumify-data/lumify-public/web/war/src/main/webapp/node_modules/grunt-notify/lib/platforms../bin/Grunt.app/Contents/MacOS/Grunt ENOENT
```

Grunt-notify is installed and works when I run it from the command line. Could someone point me in the direction of where to even look?  Is there a config file laying around someplace that I missed?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: No, sorry.  I haven't been able to figure it out.  Its maddening.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when I updated node/npm.
You can see it's been discussed here - the issue is due to incorrect paths: https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify/issues/118

They have made a fix for it so you'll need to update the version of grunt-notify you are using in your package.json to: "grunt-notify": "^0.4.5"

Then run:
npm uninstall grunt-notify
npm install grunt-notify